# Fundamental Theorem of Calculus- Calculate the derivative of the Integral

Tags: calculus, integration

The Question is

$$ \frac d{dx} \int_0^{8x^2} \frac{t\cdot dt}{t+3} $$

I'm not fully solid on the FTC, However, i think that the first step should give

$$ \frac{x+dx}{x+3} $$

However, I'm not entirely sure.

Comment: I'd recommend looking at the Leibniz integral rule https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule

Answer (score 3):

There should not be a $+ dx$ term in your answer. Recall that $\frac{d}{dx}\int_{a}^{f(x)}g(t)dt = g(f(x)) \cdot \frac{d}{dx}[f(x)].$ So your answer should be $\boxed{\frac{8x^{2}}{8x^{2} + 3} \cdot 16x}.$

Answer (score 3):

leibniz rule of differencing gives you $$d \left(\int_0^{8x^2} \frac{t}{t+ 3}\, dt \right)= \frac{8x^2}{8x^2 + 3}\, d\left(8x^2\right) = \frac{8x^2}{8x^2 + 3} 16x\, dx$$
now dividing by $dx$  should give you the answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

let 
$$h(x)=\int_0^{8x^2} \frac{t\cdot dt}{t+3} $$
and $$ f(s)=\int_0^{s} \frac{t\cdot dt}{t+3} $$
so $h(x)=f(8x^2) $ then use the Chain-Role